# Set a kendo dropdown value in a function

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, razor, kendo-ui, dropdown

I have a two kendo dropdown lists to select State for address entry on a page. I have a check box to copy the first address to the second address. I need to be able to reference and set the value of the kendo dropdown list.

The dropdown lists:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.physicalAddress.State)
    .Name("physicalAddress.State")
    .DataTextField("name")
    .DataValueField("value") 
    .OptionLabel("Physical State")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["StateList"]))

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.mailingAddress.State)
    .Name("mailingAddress.State")
    .DataTextField("name")
    .DataValueField("value")
    .OptionLabel("Mailing State")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["StateList"]))
```

The function that I'm trying to write:

```
function copyInfo(f) {

        if (document.getElementById("copyCheckBox").checked) {

            //I'm hoping something exists like this
            [SecondDropDown].value = [FirstDropDown].value;

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copyInfo(f) {   
    if (document.getElementById("copyCheckBox").checked) { 
        var FirstDropDown= $("#dropdownlist1").data("kendoDropDownList");
        var SecondDropDown= $("#dropdownlist2").data("kendoDropDownList");   
        SecondDropDown.value(FirstDropDown.value());
    }
 }
```

Where dropdownlist1 and dropdownlist2 are the DOM IDs of the containing element.

See the API DEMO: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/api

Docs for value():  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-value

Comment: The problem is that [SecondDropDown] and [FirstDropDown] are placeholders, and I don't know how to actually reference the kendogrid element from the script section of the page. I should have been more clear about that in my main post, sorry.

Comment: @user5655541, i have updated the answer. Use the DOM element IDs to get the dropdown widget.

Comment: I don't know what the DOM element IDs are for these dropdown lists. I've tried using the .name().

Comment: @user5655541 whatever you put in your `.Name()` property in the html is the ID given to that element. if you put `.Name("bla")` then to access that dropdown you'd do `$("#bla").data("kendoDropDownList")` so by putting `.Name("physicalAddress.State")` you're actually setting the ID to that string and not to the property. Try doing `.Name(Model.physicalAddress.State)` maybe?

Comment: The name is
    .Name("physicalAddress.State")

I tried referencing it by
    $("#physicalAddress.State").data("kendoDropDownList")

but that didn't work. Changing the name to .Name("Model.physicalAddress.State") causes the entire model for that form to be passed back to the controller as nulls.